# Error de CORS el enviar un formulario con FormData()

Tags: reactjs, formularios, fetch, cors

Llevo un par de días peleándome con fetch en ReactJS para enviar este formulario que incluye un título, una descripción y una imagen.

Estoy utilizando el método bien? hay algo que se me pase por alto?

El método `JSON.stringify` en otro formulario de la aplicación funciona de maravilla. Pero creo que hay algo que estoy haciendo mal en `FormData()`

recibo el típico error de `CORS`

> Access to fetch at 'WWW' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```js
const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('title', title)
        formData.append('description', description)
        formData.append('image', selectedFile)

        
        console.log(selectedFile)
        console.log(title)
        console.log(description)
        
         
        fetch('endpoint!', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json",
                       "Autorization": "Bearer la key",
                       "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
            body: formData
        }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then ((res) => {
            console.log('Enviao!!', res)
            window.location.reload()
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('ERROR JODER!', error)
        }) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas espero ayudarte un poco.

Puedes añadir esto a la cabecera y ver si se soluciona el error

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

No se si te servirá pero de dejo el el siguiente link donde te explican detalladamente el error y te dan algunas soluciones.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Poniéndolo simple tu error es porque por motivos de seguridad se prohíben que se puedan cargar o recibir datos de un servidor ajeno al tuyo, es decir que estas recibiendo datos de un servidor distinto y salta el CORS.

Te dejo otro link donde te explican CORS

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Solo que las políticas de CORS se especifican en del backend, por ejemplo en Spring puedes usar `@CrossOrigin`, en Node js puedes usar `app.use(cors())`, así que depende que  se use como backend